# How to get Token balances

Tags: erc-20, tokens, nft, api

How to get balances of all ERC 20 tokens a wallet holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work with QuickNode*

You can get all the ERC20 tokens in a wallet address by using just one custom QuickNode RPC [qn_getWalletTokenBalance](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/qn_getWalletTokenBalance_v2)

To use this, enable the [Token and NFT API bundle Add-on](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/token-and-nft-api-v2-bundle) on your QuickNode Ethereum endpoint, then use this script:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "id": 67,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "qn_getWalletTokenBalance",
  "params": [{
    "wallet": "0xd8da6bf26964af9d7eed9e03e53415d37aa96045"
  }]
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("QUICKNODE_URL_HERE", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Check this video and learn how to create a token balance app: https://youtu.be/ReW6Giid43w

Comment: If you are working for QuickNode you should disclose the relationship in your answer. Adding to the name isn't enough.

Comment: I've added that to the answer; I thought having it straight on my name makes more sense. I will be cautious moving forward.

Answer (score 5):

To get all the ERC20 Tokens Balance, you can use [Moralis API](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm)

```js
const Moralis = require("moralis").default;
const { EvmChain } = require("@moralisweb3/common-evm-utils");

const runApp = async () => {
  await Moralis.start({
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    // ...and any other configuration
  });

  const address = "0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d";

  const chain = EvmChain.ETHEREUM;

  const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.token.getWalletTokenBalances({
    address,
    chain,
  });

  console.log(response.raw);
};

runApp();
```

And this is the expected result

```json
  {
    "token_address": "0x709b5a3c7a22250981869a8080a354de919f821e",
    "symbol": "DMON",
    "name": "DogeMon",
    "logo": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "decimals": 9,
    "balance": "500000000000000",
    "possible_spam": true
  },
  {
    "token_address": "0x2df495dfc4a24064acc573e9ec9f5bd509b42e40",
    "symbol": "GAMEBOY",
    "name": "Nintendo Gameboy",
    "logo": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "decimals": 18,
    "balance": "1500000000000000000000000000",
    "possible_spam": true
  },
  {
    "token_address": "0xb2ea9527bf05bc3b73320a1ec18bd4f2fe88d952",
    "symbol": "OP",
    "name": "Optimism",
    "logo": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "decimals": 18,
    "balance": "767387143779415173800484933",
    "possible_spam": true
  },
```

You can find a guide for erc 20 token balance here: [How to get all ERC20 tokens owned by an address](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-all-erc20-tokens-owned-by-an-address)

Disclosure: I work at Moralis

Answer (score 0):

etherscan: https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/tokens#get-address-erc20-token-holding

alchemy: https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-get-all-tokens-owned-by-an-address

covalenthq: https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/balances/get-token-balances-for-address/

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I work at Chainbase
You can use this api to get all the token balance you want.

```
curl --request GET \
     --url 'https://api.chainbase.online/v1/account/tokens?chain_id=1&address=0xd8dA6BF26964aF9D7eEd9e03E53415D37aA96045' \
     --header 'accept: application/json' \
     --header 'x-api-key: xxxx'
```

You can see the link below.
https://docs.chainbase.com/reference/getaccounttokens